# Programmatically adding a lot of columns to DataGrid is too slow

Tags: wpf, multithreading, datagrid, wpfdatagrid, datagridcolumn

I have a WPF DataGrid that must have the row headers and columns added programmatically. I've implemented this successfully but the performance is not acceptable. Each time a column is added the `ColumnCollection` puts out a `CollectionChangedEvent`. I have not found a way to disable this event so I've investigated other ways of improving performance.

I have created the DataGrid on a background thread and attempted to add the grid to the UI, without success, getting the following message:

```
"UI Element is owned by a different thread"
```

I've created the DataGrid on the main UI thread and tried to add the columns in a background thread. Same issue. I cannot ask the UI thread to do it as that's the problem in the first place.

What other approaches are used to add a lot of columns to a DataGrid? (in one case 10,000 columns)

Janene

Comment: Do you use the Dispatcher on your DataGrid to do the work in background? Maybe a piece of your codebehind would be useful!

Comment: Why use threads? Tasks are the way to go

Comment: Have you considered ListView GridView?   Not as many features as DataGrid but faster and lighter.

Comment: Blam - I need the ability to scroll it to a specific column; thought about ListView but it doesn't off enough
Arjang & @Michele - I ended up using the Dispatcher, but with priority of Background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using this line of code to create the DataGrid in the Background and add it to the UI.

```
 this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new UpdateNodesDelegate(UpdateNodes));
```

Got this solution from the book **WPF Recipes in C# 2008**.

Janene